# What are the time columns output in pg:outliers and pg:calls

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

The columns output from pg:outliers and pg:calls are:

```
qry | total_exec_time | prop_exec_time | ncalls  |  sync_io_time
```

What is the definition of

- total_exec_time, prop_exec_time, and sync_io_time
- pg:outliers vs. pg:calls

Answer (score 0):

I've got part of the answer

- pg:outliers: show 10 queries that have longest execution time in aggregate.
- pg:calls: show 10 most frequently called queries.

Answer (score -1):

Source https://github.com/heroku/heroku-pg-extras:
Here quoting the documentation:

> This command displays statements, obtained from pg_stat_statements,
> ordered by the amount of time to execute in aggregate. This includes
>
> - the statement itself,
> - the total execution time for that statement,
> - the proportion of total execution time for all statements that statement has taken up,
> - the number of times that statement has been called,
> - the amount of time that statement spent on synchronous I/O (reading/writing from the filesystem).

Comment: However, the quote you're using specifically refers to `pg:outliers`. Can you please relate that to the question being asked, ie. compare with `pg:calls`? Also, there's another part of that question: What are total_exec_time, prop_exec_time, and sync_io_time?

Comment: @GeneralGrievance please open or actually read the documentation i quoted.
It state that `pg:calls` is much like pg:outliers, but ordered by the number of times a statement has been called.

So the command `pg:calls` has no documentation as we should refer to the `pg:outliers`.

And if you were more prone to read instad of trying to blame me, you would notice that the 5 colums of the questions actually matches the 5 bullets points I am quoting.

I think it would be more useful for everyone to help refine the anwer than blaming someone for trying to answer. Let's build on each other :)

Comment: OK, great. That's the kind of thing that should be included in answers. Generally answers are better when quoted material is explained by you, the author. My intention is not to blame you at all, and I do not personally agree with the downvote, but to help you to improve your answer.